# how to resolve 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'query' in Python flask>

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

```
models.py
```

import os
from sqla_wrapper import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin

db = SQLAlchemy(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL", "sqlite:///db.sqlite"))  # this connects to a database either on Heroku or on localhost

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):

```
__tablename__ = 'accounts'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) # primary keys are required by SQLAlchemy
email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
password = db.Column(db.String(100))
name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
```

```
auth.py
```

```
# auth.py

from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, flash
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, login_required
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from models import User, db

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)


@auth.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')


@auth.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login_post():
    email = request.form.get('email')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    remember = True if request.form.get('remember') else False

    user = db.query(User).filter_by(email=email).first()

    # check if user actually exists
    # take the user supplied password, hash it, and compare it to the hashed password in database
    if not user or not check_password_hash(user.password, password):
        flash('Please check your login credentials and try again.')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))  # if user doesn't exist or password is wrong, reload the page

    # if the above check passes, then we know the user has the right credentials
    login_user(user, remember=remember)
    flash('You have been logged in.')
    return redirect(url_for('main.profile'))


@auth.route('/signup')
def signup():
    return render_template('signup.html')


@auth.route('/signup', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def signup_post():
    email = request.form.get('email')
    name = request.form.get('name')
    password = request.form.get('password')

    user = db.query(User).filter_by(email=email).first()  # if this returns a user, then the email already exists in database

    if user:  # if a user is found, we want to redirect back to signup page so user can try again
        flash('Email address already exists')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.signup'))

    # create new user with the form data. Hash the password so plaintext version isn't saved.
    new_user = User(email=email, name=name, password=generate_password_hash(password, method='sha256'))

    # add the new user to the database
    db.add(new_user)
    db.commit()

    # code to validate and add user to database goes here
    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))


@auth.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    flash('You have been logged out.')
    return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
```

I tried to create a new user but it resulted to AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'query'

Comment: Try `db.session.query`, see the example in the documentation https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/#query-the-data

Comment: it now gives 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'session'

Comment: Maybe we are not talking about the same object, so you need to provide more input. I was assuming that your `SQLAlchemy` object is an instance of `flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy` which would have a `session` attribute, see https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/main/src/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py#L142. However, you are importing it from `sqla_wrapper`, so maybe you are dealing with a custom implementation where I cannot help you without knowing the underlying code.